# SQL Server : unique default values

Tags: sql-server, random, unique

I have a table with a column of type `nchar(16)` that is automatically filled with random characters generated by setting the default value of the column to `dbo.randomtext((16))` (a scalar function). There will be about 1M records in the table.

I know that the likelihood of getting non-unique values is low, but is there some way to ensure that this does not happen and the column is really unique?

What will happen if I define the column as `UNIQUE` and the random text generated is not unique?

I am using SQL Server 2016 Standard edition.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you should really be using is a `SEQUENCE`, `IDENTITY` or `uniqueidentity` and this smells like you are "reinventing" the wheel.

As for the questions you ask:

> I know that the likelihood of getting non-unique values is low, but is there some way to ensure that this does not happen and the column is really unique?

Yes, create a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the column. Then every row, must have a unique in that column.

> What will happen if I define the column as `UNIQUE` and the random text generated is not unique?

If there is already at least one duplicate in the column, then creating the `INDEX`/`CONSTRAINT` will fail; you'll need to ensure you `DELETE`/`UPDATE` any duplicates before you can create the `INDEX`/`CONSTRAINT`. If it is an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` it will fail, and entire DML statement will not take affect (the new row(s) won't be inserted, or the row(s) won't be updated).

Comment: SEQUENCE, IDENTITY and uniqueidentity cannot be used as these are supposed to be random values which can not be guessable. The values are created upon INSERTs and what I wanted to know is if there is a way to tell MSSQL to automatically avoid failure and generate a new value if there is duplication.

Comment: `uniqueidentity` can't be guessed... At best, it could be calculated, but you would need to know a lot of information about the instance, and know the time down to the something like the nearest 1/1000000th of a second.

Comment: uniqueidentity should not be used for security purposes according to micorsoft itself. see for example https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150701-00/?p=45241

Comment: That says don't use them for passwords @user1480192 ... It says nothing about don't use them... Don't take an article and read one part of a longer sentence and read something entirely different....

Comment: What does this question have to do with security anyway?

Comment: Also, in fact, in you read that article properly, @user1480192 , you'll see it tells you *"This is a really bad idea. GUIDs are **designed for uniqueness**, not for security."*